compilation failure with std::any and multiply function
https://godbolt.org/z/hxaq93ebc
The multiply function of double and int fails to compile. I am not sure why it is happening. I tried it on with different compilers, but it didn't work.
It appears something else is missing here.
I tried with other operators, looks like with multiplication is not working.
Full code:

#include <iostream>
#include <any>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <typeinfo>

struct GenericBinaryOperation {
    template <typename Func>
    std::any operator()(const std::any& lhs, const std::any& rhs, Func&& func) const {
        // Handle integer and double operation
        if (lhs.type() == typeid(int) && rhs.type() == typeid(double)) {
            return func(std::any_cast<int>(lhs), std::any_cast<double>(rhs));
        } else if (lhs.type() == typeid(double) && rhs.type() == typeid(int)) {
            return func(std::any_cast<double>(lhs), std::any_cast<int>(rhs));
        }
        // Handle double and double
        else if (lhs.type() == typeid(double) && rhs.type() == typeid(double)) {
            return func(std::any_cast<double>(lhs), std::any_cast<double>(rhs));
        }
        // Handle integer and integer
        else if (lhs.type() == typeid(int) && rhs.type() == typeid(int)) {
            return func(std::any_cast<int>(lhs), std::any_cast<int>(rhs));
        }
        // Handle string and string (e.g., concatenation)
        else if (lhs.type() == typeid(std::string) && rhs.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
            return func(std::any_cast<std::string>(lhs), std::any_cast<std::string>(rhs));
        } else {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Unsupported or mismatched types");
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    GenericBinaryOperation operation;

    // Integer and double addition
    std::any a = 5;
    std::any b = 3.5;
    auto add = [](auto x, auto y) { return x + y; };
    std::cout << "Add (int + double): " << std::any_cast<double>(operation(a, b, add)) << std::endl;

    // Double and integer multiplication
    std::any c = 2.5f;
    std::any d = 4;
    auto multiply = [](auto x, auto y) { return x * y; };
    std::cout << "Multiply (double * int): " << std::any_cast<double>(operation(c, d, multiply)) << std::endl;

    // String concatenation
    std::any e = std::string("Hello, ");
    std::any f = std::string("World!");
    auto concatenate = [](auto x, auto y) { return x + y; };
    std::cout << "Concatenate (string + string): " << std::any_cast<std::string>(operation(e, f, add)) << std::endl;

    // Example of mismatched types causing an exception
    try {
        std::any g = 42;
        std::any h = std::string("Forty-Two");
        operation(g, h, add); // This will throw an exception due to type mismatch
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


do you actually need the runtime type erasure from std::any ? I suppose not, unless the code you posted here is very much simplified. In your example code you know all types involved beforehand. If you need one single variable to hold std::string later an int and later a double all in the same variable you could use std::any for that. Though merely to pass arguments of different type to a function can be done much simpler.

Hi, I am trying to implement a pandas dataframe like datastructure, where column types could be heterogenous, so i could have gone with variant or any. So, i had to implement some kind of visitor pattern to access the underlying data and apply binary/unary function on it.

ok so it is an oversimplified example :) (thats of course ok). Though, did you consider std::variant ?

The issue is that there's a path in your function that can ultimately try to call std::string * std::string.  The fact your example doesn't do that is irrelevant, since the compiler still has to consider that path through your function.
If you really need this level of generality, you can add type checks to your lambda.  These would be runtime checks, not compile time, but that's probably the best you can do unless somebody much smarter than me has a more clever solution.

you can make the compiler to check that the function is invocable with a std::string before it tries to create the function to avoid the compile time error, the problem here is that this check only happens on the immediate context so you are forced to write a trailing return type.
auto multiply = [](auto x, auto y) -> decltype(x*y) { return x * y; };

for more complex requirements you can use a concept instead of a trailing return type.
now you can check that the function is invocable with those arguments before you call it, this is a compile-time check, and so if it fails the compiler won't even try to create the function.
// Handle string and string (e.g., concatenation)
if constexpr (std::invocable<Func, std::string&, std::string&>)
{
    if (lhs.type() == typeid(std::string) && rhs.type() == typeid(std::string))
    {
        return func(std::any_cast<std::string>(lhs), std::any_cast<std::string>(rhs));

    }
}

godbolt demo

side-note: std::any is a big object, storing an int in it is a waste of space compared to int64_t, lastly consider using a std::variant<int64_t, double, std::string>, and you will get to use std::visit instead of having to spell out each combination yourself, also you don't allow users to make your mistake of storing a float instead of double, because the object cannot store a float.
also numpy arrays are more like std::variant<std::vector<double>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<float> ....> that's how it is able to store smaller types more densely, because all vector objects are the same size, but the buffers will be of different size ... and it is written in C, but it is the same concept, pandas dataframes are just a vector of these where each column is an array ... but there are other modes of storage.
